# CorsConfiguration.setMaxAge is not working in SpringBoot Application

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I am trying to set Cache-Control in Application using **CorsConfiguration**. Ideally when I call the `Rest Api` in DHC or `PostMan` I should be getting Cache-Control Max Age 3600, but I am getting below Response:
**Cache-Control : no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate**

Someone Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Following is my `Application.java class`

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);   }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setMaxAge(3600L);
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: CorsConfiguration.setMaxAge intentionally by design has no effect on the Cache-Control header. So what’s described in the question is expected behavior. Access-Control-Max-Age is the header that CorsConfiguration.setMaxAge actually affects. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age. Note also: Access-Control-Max-Age header is only sent in response to the CORS preflight OPTIONS request. Per the docs: *“how long, in seconds, **the response from a pre-flight request** can be cached by clients.”* So browsers ignore it if sent in GET, POST, etc responses.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, Thank you for the response, I understood what you said above, but when I set "config.setMaxAge(3600L);" this why am I not getting Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600 in the response when I call API.

Comment: If config.setMaxAge is set to a value different from the cache control max age value, which one will take priority in terms of caching the preflight